# Inserting logo image into application

Tags: android, imageview

I have been trying and trying whole day yesterday to insert my logo image in my application. But with no luck.
I was using ImageView and I was applying all advices from the Internet and I have builded over 50 APK to test it out, and every time it is a  failure.

My image was in drawable-nodpi, drawable-xdpi, drawable-xxdpi, drawable-xxxdpi and in mipmap also etc.
Also, I have tried different formats of image and sizes. My last size of image was **300x408px**
On Android Studio image is showing but not on ANY device or tablet.
Here is source code

file **main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="0">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="Pusti" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:text="Zaustavi" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/tower"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3" />
```

file **MusicAndroidActivity.java**

```
    package clever.radio;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.id;

public class MusicAndroidActivity extends Activity {

    static MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    Button buttonPlay;
    Button buttonStop;
    String url = "http://radioclever.stream:8000/stream";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

file **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="clever.radio"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MusicAndroidActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Radio Clever</string>
</resources>
```

and **dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Any error log @Luka?

Comment: Have to tried putting the image in drawable folder?

Comment: post you activity code as well

Comment: have you tried with **android:src** insted of **app:srcCompat**

Comment: Where you getting findviewbyid **imageView4** of ImageView in activity?

Comment: use android:src and check is your image .png

Comment: @ibtehaz if you mean on Android Studio, no. I couldn't see logs in my phone cuz' I didn't rooted it yet.

Comment: @AbhayBohra as I wrote above I did.

Comment: @Akash No, I will try that next.

Comment: @KuldeepKulkarni I do not understand your question, code is inserted automatically by AndroidStudio when i dragged ImageView into preview.

Comment: @OgnevZair My image is PNG, and i'll try that.

Comment: @RahulKhurana main.xml is main activity, i renamed it.

Comment: @LukaPerazic, you wont need to root your phone to see error logs. you will always see the logs on the bottom of your android studio after loading!

Comment: @Akash Thanks very much. It's working now. post answer so i can accept it

Comment: @cricket_007 as far as I know .java is java right? so my post includes java code

Comment: You mean the tags? The Android tag is redundant with the Java tag in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:src` insted of `app:srcCompat`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check findViewById for Imageview.

You did not get Imageview without it.

Comment: Wrong tag, sorry, i though @Akash answer was useful, android:src worked perfectly with no further edits. thank anyway may help someone else come here

Comment: Please don't comment to tell people to vote. Also only use code blocks for code